# How to click on <input type=file> across browsers using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm working on dealing with a file-chooser dialog using Selenium 2 - WebDriver. Believe it or not, my problem is NOT dealing with the OS-native file-chooser. That part I can handle!

The problem is getting Selenium to properly click on the "Choose File" button. Since the original source html is simply `<input type='file'>`, the browser determines how to render it as a field and a button. As a result, the placement and naming of the button changes depending on browser. I've got it working in Chrome, but only because Chrome places the button on the leftmost alignment and Selenium happens to click there by default.

Any ideas? It's not clear to me if an input of this type is truly navigable from within the DOM anyway...

Comment: As I know there is no possibility to choose file (e.g. for upload) in such way. If you want to do it, simply type path to file in this input.

Answer (score 54):

The proper way to upload a file on any OS is to

1. Find the `<input type='file'>` element. You need not to worry about different implementations and exact positioning. Just find the element for example by xpath `//input[@type='file']`
2. `sendKeys()` or `type()` (or whatever method writes text into elements in your language) the path to file to that input element.

Sample Java code:

```
// find the input element
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
// 'type' the file location to it as it were a usual <input type='text' /> element
elem.sendKeys("C://path/To/File.jpg");
```

This works on every OS and browser in WebDriver.

Comment: alternative could be
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']").sendKeys(YourfielPath)`
with the cssSelector you got more and easier to use ways to find an element without name/id (my opinion)

Comment: When I use SendKeys() for the element, I get `OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element cannot contain user-editable text`. I think that newer versions of Selenium are more strict about how/when you can send keyboard input. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is most strange. This really is a proper and documented way to upload files. I guess you are using the newest Selenium 2.20.0, right? Which language? Any other special technologies? Could you also test your case in, say, Firefox and IE (where things work smoothly for me with Java)? Or Selenium 2.17.0? If everything fails, something is wrong. In that case, attach a minimal test for us, please, and after a confirmation, we'll file a bug.

Comment: Have you figured out this ? Having the same issue. SendKeys() on input type=file does nothing.

Comment: What OS, browser, selenium version and language? Any special technology stack on the webpage (i.e. Silverlight, flash etc.)?

Comment: @MartinFabik Are you absolutely sure you yre trying with an absolute path to the file you want to upload? The Browse window needs an absolute path, not path relative to your current java application workdir.

Comment: I'm using 2.24.0.0 (C#) and this method worked for me exactly as Slanec reported.

Comment: Works for me too. Are you sure the file input tag isn't readonly?

Comment: Doesn't work if the input element won't accept typed input.  Mine forces the dialog in all cases.

Comment: @SkipHuffman The dialog always shows, anyways. The input isn't typed into the input, but into the dialog (yes, it's a dirty hack not to introduce a `uploadFile()` method for this, but blame Selenium devs). Shouldn't be a problem, really. Can you point me to a input where it fails?

Comment: @Slanec File upload for www.playstream.com  you can see it on an eval account.

Comment: In my case, finding the element by Id only caused the dialog to appear. No text was entered. But, if the element was found via XPath using `input[@type='file']`, then it worked great.

Comment: Since there is no language tag, here is the python syntax: `elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
elem.send_keys("C://path/To/File.jpg")`

Comment: @SkipHuffman, Doesn't work if the input element won't accept typed input. Agreed with you on above point. What's the best way to do the file upload if sendKeys doesnt work.

Comment: @AnilReddyYarragonda Would you have a publicly accessible example?

Comment: @Slanec, Nope. My input field is not accepting any text. SendKeys doesnt work in that case. Am i right?

Comment: @AnilReddyYarragonda No idea. I haven't ever seen a file input element that would not work with `sendKeys()`, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

Have exactly the same situation with element `<input type='file'>`. In my case it is created using ExtJS.

I don't know whether you have solved this question or not but let me provide my solution.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Neither sendKeys() or type() nor using ActionBuilder was helpful for me. The only JavascriptExecutor works like a charm.

Comment: So by clicking you get the OS' filechooser dialog but how can you specify a file after that? I'm afraid selenium cannot control this dialog or am I wrong?

Comment: Hallo, @Sebastian. And then you can upload file using AutoIt http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit. And here you can see an example. Ist das Ok fur dich? ;)

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I hoped for a solution with selenium and javascript only. But thank you / Dankeschön :)

Comment: Unfortunately WebDriver is not able to interact with native OS windows. I made the solution using AUtoIT and it was just fine. Here is an example (in russian but code is selfdescribing) http://internetka.in.ua/autoit-file-upload/

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = await driver.findElements(By.css("input[type='file']"));
if (input && input.length > 0) {
  try {
    await input[0].sendKeys(url);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I tested with the following element:

```
<INPUT style="WIDTH: 550px; background-color:yellow" type="file">
```

Results:

- IE: **doubleclick** on any area of the element, the "Choose File" dialogue would occur;
- Firefox: **click** on any area of the element, the "Choose File" dialogue would occur.