# How to click on a file field button implemented in ExtJS using Selenium?

Tags: extjs, selenium-ide, filefield

I an testing an application implemented in ExtJs.
I need to click on a button implemented as a filefield to upload a file.
I am not able to click on the button using Selenium IDE.
Infact I have tried the same on similar buttons(that have been implemented as filefield).

Can someone please guide me as to how to do this using Selenium IDE?

Here is the how the button is implemented:

```
<td id="filefield-1262-browseButtonWrap" style="width: 92px;">
<div id="filefield-1262-buttonEl" class="x-btn x-form-file-btn x-btn-default-small x-                noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon" style="border-width:1px 1px 1px 1px;">
<em id="filefield-1262-buttonEl-btnWrap">
<button id="filefield-1262-buttonEl-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off"   role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button">
**<span id="filefield-1262-buttonEl-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="background-color: transparent;">Import Local File</span>**
<span id="filefield-1262-buttonEl-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon "></span>
</button>
</em>
<input id="filefield-1262-fileInputEl" class="x-form-file-input" type="file" size="1" name="ipListFile">
</div>
</td>
```

Thanks,
Harpal

Comment: how about just adding the path to the filefield and clicking the submit button?

Comment: Maybe this question would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver