# Local Chrome extension to set file of input type="file"

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-chrome-extension, file-io

I'am developing an Extension for Chrome browser.
I wan't to choose a file from a `input type="file"` html element using the extension.
But I know this is not possible due to security restrictions.

Is there a way to **remove the security restrictions of Chrome** related to this issue so that this will be possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i'm going to answer my own question.

First of all thank Michael Dibbets and wtjones for your answers.
`--disable-web-security and --allow-file-access-from-files` did not work.
I did not go for native plugins and for extending chrome from its source as it seems to take time.

### The solution:

I used [chromedriver](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver) with [selenium java](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) to automate chrome.

and with the help of [Slanec's Answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver) i was able select the file pragmatically.

#### Here's the java code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/.../chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("URL_OF_THE_PAGE");
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("TEXT_IN_THE_LINK"));
link.click();
WebElement choose_file_input = driver.findElement(By.className("CLASS_OF_THE_INPUT"));
choose_file_input.sendKeys("PATH_TO_FILE");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is this an extension for personal use only? If so, you may be able to use --disable-web-security and --allow-file-access-from-files. Otherwise you might need to use a native plugin: https://code.google.com/p/firebreath/

Comment: I used the method you suggested `--disable-web-security and --allow-file-access-from-files`.
And then I used this script to set the value.

`$('input').value = "path_to_file"`

but i got an error:

`InvalidStateError`
`Error: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Download the chromium source code and compile your own browser.

The security restrictions are there for a purpose and can't be cirumvented(not easily anyways)
The purpose is that an user can download an extension from the google play store and not having to be bothered about the risk that extention poses to their system.

Comment: Good idea @Michael if there are no other option. If so I will give a try.