# set value on input file element in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to set value on an input file element in content script in Chrome extension.

I find that it works to set value directly on Chrome web console, but fails if within content script. It seems that there is some security issue blocking this.

So I wonder if there is any other way?

Comment: You can't manipulate DOM with a content script?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: You may find the solution in the: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249185/local-chrome-extension-to-set-file-of-input-type-file?rq=1