# Selenium WebDriver ElementNotVisible Error for input type='file' element

Tags: ruby, file-io, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to try and emulate file uploads

I have a file input field:

```
<input class="upload_file_field" id="main_image_file" label="false" name="banner_image_file" type="file" />
```

Using this in my test results in a ElementNotVisibleError

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "main_image_file").send_keys "/Users/dan/Desktop/sample.jpg"
```

I even tried to change the visibility before trying to upload the file:

```
@driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility='visible'; arguments[0].style.display='block'; arguments[0].style.height='100px'; arguments[0].style.width='100px'; arguments[0].style.opacity=1; arguments[0].style.zindex=20", @driver.find_element(:id, "main_image_file"))
```

It still results in an ElementNotVisibleError

Any advice would be much appreciated

**UPDATE**

Okay, turns out that there are several conditions which can make an element hidden:

1. Cannot have 0 opacity
2. Must have length and width > 0
3. Cannot be hidden visibility
4. Display can't be none
5. transform property can move elements off the page which make it not visible

My problem was with the transform property. it was a way of hiding the input field by transforming it off the page completely so I could use a nicer style button using jQuery file-upload.

After that,

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "main_image_file").send_keys "/Users/dan/Desktop/sample.jpg"
```

worked perfectly well in emulating user selection of a file

Comment: Which browser are you using? I have faced this same issue with Chrome when the element is hidden behind the div and it needs to scrolled down to get the element visible. But in Firefox there is auto scroll and hence you won't see this error.

Answer (score 0):

It simply may be the case that the page didn't load because of some error. Could you try to error out with:

```
raise(@driver.page_source.to_s)
```

just before the find_element command?

This way you could make sure that the input field is actually on the page, as seen by Selenium.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the input field is indeed seen by selenium.

Answer (score 0):

you use Ruby but anyway if this question is still actual for you then please take a look at the similar question where I offered the answer [How to click on <input type=file> across browsers using Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver/17496241#17496241)