# How to control file chooser with Selenium 2?

Tags: testing, browser, selenium, gui-testing

The [selenium website](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) claims:

> It drives the browser much more effectively and over comes the
>   limitations of Selenium 1.x which affected our functional test
>   coverage, like the file upload or download, pop-ups and dialogs
>   barrier

But I know only of more or less strange hacks using AutoIt or AWT KeyEvents.

So, how can I tell Selenium to put a certain path into the file dialog (not the form element that opened the file dialog!) and click on 'OK'?

Comment: Usually, dependant on the browser & the client bindings, you should just be able to do a `.SendKeys` to the file upload control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to click on <input type=file> across browsers using Selenium Webdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Whoa, I may have flagged this question as a duplicate prematurely. I didn't read _"(not the form element that opened the file dialog!)"_ and considered this to be a "How to upload in WebDriver" question again. Why don't you want to put the path into the form element (`<input type="file" />`) but into the OS dialog? The answer is that you can't, because WebDriver's way is to use the `sendKeys()` method without clicking the element, because WebDriver can't handle broswer/OS modal dialogs (like the file chooser one). Does the `sendKeys()` solution work for you?