# WebDriver: input type=file - how to attach a file when filing the form

Tags: java, selenium, input, webdriver

I am testing web application with Selenium, WebDriver, Jbehave, Thucydides.

When I try to choose file when filling the form:

```
WebElementFacade wef = find(By.cssSelector("#inputTypeFileId"));
wef.type("/data/file.txt");
```

I get such an exception:

```
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebdriverAssertionError: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
```

I cannot find a solution for attaching files in JBehave tests. How should I point a file to upload when testing web applications?

Kind Regards,
Lukasz

Comment: Hi, I think this topic will be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver/17496241#17496241

Comment: Thanks a lot - solution with Autoit works like a charm. I am lucky, that I am using Windows, not Linux... Cheers!

Comment: Vote requires 15 reputation :(