# How to attach files using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I wanted to add attachment using Selenium webdriver. My input tag looks like this.

`Input` tag

```
<input id="5465465456461763_input" type="file" name="_attFile_" multiple="" tabindex="0"/>
```

I am using this code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='_attFile_']")).sendKeys("D:/foldername/filename");
```

Output: 0B uploaded

What could be wrong in this method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to click on <input type=file> across browsers using Selenium Webdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

I request you to use AutoIt script:

Title of the window used for uploading the fileWinWaitActive("File
 Upload")  ;

File to be `uploadedSend("C:\samplefile.txt") Send("{ENTER}")`

Save this file as AddFile.au3.

And then use the following code to call the exe file

created by compiling the above AutoIt script

```
try {                    
String[] commands = new String[]{};             
commands = new String[]{"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AutoIt3\\Examples\\Addfile.exe"}; //location of the autoit executable   
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);    
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
}

WebElement addFileElement = driver.findElement(By.className("add-file")); // you can find the element to upload the file in different way,  class name used  here, you can use xpath

 addFileElement.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF WinExists("File Upload") Then
   WinWaitActive("File Upload")
   ControlSetText("File Upload","",1148,"C:\src.zip")
   ControlClick("File Upload","",1)


Else
   MsgBox(1,"ERROR","UNABLE TO VIEW THE FOLDER")
EndIf
```

This is auto it .au3 file.
you need to install auto it and create any file, say "upload.au3"
right click on this file and compile it to create upload.exe
Now, in webdriver code, write the below code

```
---->>>
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='_attFile_']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("F:\\AutoIt\\upload.exe");
---->>>
```