# Upload file with webdriver when input is hidden

Tags: upload, webdriver, hidden

I'm not able to upload a file and I guess the problem is because input object is hidden!

I have a lot of uploads in my tests but they all use "" and everything works perfectly

This is the first time I have to use something like the code below

Another question is why it works if I start my test from selenium IDE but not when I start it from my framework ( testNG+webdriver)

Code line is:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("C:\test.txt");

Object structure is:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" flow-btn="">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"/>
    <span>Upload files</span>
    <input type="file" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" multiple="multiple"/>
</button>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver/17496241#17496241 There are several possible variants of solving the problem.

Comment: Great, I solved my problem in this way:

Answer (score 1):

Great,

I solved my problem in this way and , it works perfectly!
But, I'm wondering if this is the only way. I mean, make the object visible !

```
    String js = "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';";
    jse.executeScript(js, element);
    element.sendKeys("C:\\test.txt");
    String jsa = "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';";
    jse.executeScript(jsa, element);
```