# Handling load file dialog with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to handle 'select files to load' dialog with the help of selenium webdriver.
Here is HTML:

```
<form class="upload">
    <button class="btn" data-capture="" type="button">Browse</button>
    <input class="hide" type="file" accept="..." multiple="" data-file-input=""/>
</form>
```

What i'm trying to do:

1. remove class='hide';
2. senndkeys with file path, after elemnt is unhidden;
3. hide element back.

Here is the code to do this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("$('.hide:not(.layout)').removeClass('hide')");
(webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".upload>input"))).sendKeys("path_to_file");
js.executeScript("$('.hide:not(.layout)').addClass('hide')");
```

But i got exception on 3rd line:

```
"Runtime.evaluate threw exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the Chrome Developer Console open at that time or the Firefox Developer Console open at that time by chance?

Comment: Does (webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".upload>input"))) find an element? Maybe wait for it to appear first.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, user1433852. It looks like the problem was really with wait. After adding waiting for ajax, it starts to work!