# Selenium ChromeDriver SendKeys breaks jQuery File Upload Plugin

Tags: selenium, jquery-file-upload, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating a UI test for a page with async file upload experience using Selenium ChromeDriver. File upload is implemented using jQuery File Upload Plugin (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) which enhances an input type="file" with additional functionality like async upload, multiple files upload, drag-n-drop support etc.

As you know, the recommended way to deal with standard input type="file" in Selenium tests is something like

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("fileinput")).SendKeys(@"c:\test.txt");
```

However, it does not work with this plugin. The server-side (in my case it is an MVC controller's POST action) does not get any calls from the client and when I open Chrome DevTools Console I can see the actual error **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**  (basically it complains about the unreachable server URI).

At the same time manually it works perfectly fine (when I navigate to the page, click Upload, choose file in Open file dialog and press Open). So it seems the problem can be in between Selenium and the upload plugin itself.

Has anyone else faced with the similar issues using jQuery File Upload Plugin + Selenium ChromeDriver? I'm running ChromeDriver version 2.9 and jQuery File Upload version 5.40.0.

Comment: It seems you follow one path while testing it yourself (via the file dialog) and other path via selenium (typing the file name). What happens when you type the name while testing yourself?

Comment: This is something that can't be handled by selenium. You have to use Robot class and/or Sikuli for that as they facilitate UI automation.

Comment: @Subh I'm curious: what exactly can't be handled by selenium?

Comment: @acdcjunior You are right, I follow two different paths because Selenium has a limitation and can't interact with Open File Dialog (as well as with any other browser's modal window). At the same time, I'm not sure how can I "type the name while testing yourself" as you suggested above? As far as I know there is no way to set a value of the file input e.g. via JavaScript. Could you please share any suggestions on the manual type approach?

Comment: @Subh You are right, it can be done this way (and I actually succeeded with Selenium + Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait, I'm from .NET/C# world) but this approach becomes very unstable when you run tests locally with minimised browser etc. So I'm looking for pure Selenium solution and wonder if maybe I'm just missing something. Because, again, Selenium.SendKeys works perfectly fine with a standard file input.

Comment: **SendKeys** will certainly work fine with the standard file input, where the [**file attribute for input is 'file'**](http://i.imgur.com/lkmT4wk.png), but it won't work where there is a case of multiple file upload and the [**file attribute for input is not file**](http://i.imgur.com/H7jAqId.png). In the latter case, you have to click on the button, and then the [**window dialog box comes up**](http://i.imgur.com/Zht4b06.png), which is out of the context of the browser and can't be handled by Selenium and hence I suggested of Robot and/or Sikuli.
Hope, it clarifies you, @adcjunior. :)

Comment: @AndreyMasarskiy: I presume you might end up relying to "Robot" or Sikuli for your problem above. I can only help you with providing the link for equivalent of **Robot** in C#, which is this: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library). For Sikuli, I am sorry I don't have any relevant link. I guess you've to google it out yourself. Cheers. :)

Comment: @AndreyMasarskiy, you may try to use path with slashes: c:/test.txt, as it is written here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @Subh Yes, I see it now, thanks for taking the time. @AndreyMasarskiy forget what I said, I didn't know that plugin and Selenium really cant handle the OS choose file dialog directly. Your only way out through Selenium is to resort to some JavaScript wizardry: Creating an `<input type="file" id="some-file-input-field">`, binding it using the jQuery-upload-plugin API [as seen here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#programmatic-file-uploads-for-browsers-without-support-for-xhr-file-uploads), and THEN calling `.SendKeys()` on `#some-file-input-field`. Seems too much, though.

Comment: Hi @acdcjunior unfortunately your suggested approach (with another element pointing to the original file input via js) does not work either (the same error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). It seems this is a plugin (jquery-file-upload) limitation and it does not work correctly with Selenium's SendKeys .