# File upload in Intern.js

Tags: javascript, testing, functional-testing, intern

It is written in documentation that it is possible to do things like file upload using intern. Can anyone provide an example of how this can be done?
I searched through examples and through LeadFoot documentation and I can't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You interact with a file input form field, just like an end-user would, with the exception that you simply “type” the absolute path to the file you want to upload from the test machine.

```
return this.remote.findById('fileInput').type('/path/to/file');
```

See also [How to click on <input type=file> across browsers using Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Path needs to be absolute, e.g. `/home/myUser/someFile.csv`