# Test with selenium for $("<input type='file'>").click()

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

Some of you may know that it's possible to ask the user to select file(s) without even putting an `<input type=file">` inside the DOM. It seems to work fine for most browsers, as long as this code is called from inside a click event handler triggered by the user.

So, basically I use this function to get an ES6 promise of file.

```
function askForFile() {
    var $input = $("<input type='file'/>");
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $input.change(e => {
           resolve(e.target.files[0]);
        });
    });
    $input.click();
    return promise;
};
```

It works perfectly fine, but can someone tell me how it can be tested with Selenium?

I've seen some Selenium [snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9735909/82609) that permit to fill a DOM input with some file:

```
// find the input element
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
// 'type' the file location to it as it were a usual <input type='text' /> element
elem.sendKeys("C://path/To/File.jpg");
```

But my input is not in the DOM so it seems I can't use this trick. Is there any way to test my code with Selenium?

Can someone tell me if there's another testable way to ask an user for file(s) without putting an useless input into the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a listener to `onclick` with Selenium ?

```
driver.executeScript('
    $(function() { 
        $("input[type=file]").on('click', function(el) {
            $(el).val('path/to/file');
        });
    })
')
```

Sorry if it's rubbish, I'm not able to test this at the moment so please consider it pseudocode :)

Comment: Then you create an input from selenium but how my app js code receive that file then? Not sure also we can set a val like that no?

Comment: No, the input gets create by your app when calling `askForFile`. Selenium just adds a listener to the `onclick` event. Indeed I'm not sure if you can specify the file path like that but you already have the code to easily test :)

Comment: but how `$("input[type=file]")` will return anything if there is no input added to the DOM?

Comment: Indeed you'll need to insert the element into the DOM and apply the listener to a parent. But as you are trying to avoid that ... not sure. You might try to overwrite your `askForFile` in the test but that requires keeping the versions in sync. Or you could wrap it in a class and keep $input as an accessible property through driver.executeScript()