# Not able to locate the button and use click function: Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to locate the button and click it in the website i am automating using selenium webdriver with java.
Could anyone Help? (using CSS selectors)

Below is the HTML for the button

```
<div class="inputWrapper newButton" name="uploadDiv">
<h6 name="fileUpload">
<label for="pdfFileUplod">Upload file</label>
</h6>
<input id="pdfFileUplod" class="fileInput hidden_" type="file" onchange="checkFile = checkFileName(this);" name="uploadFile"/>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't have a button, you have an input of type `file`. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Could you share your code as well, which have tried??

Comment: @KirilS. I appreciate the response. I tried that, its not working , i tried with absolute path and relative path too.  every time I get the same error  "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds waiting".. i gave time to wait as well, sleep(6000) its still not working

Answer (score 0):

If you think on file upload button, you have id, so use it:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.Id("pdfFileUplod"));
el.click()
```