# Button with Input tag is not clicked

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to identify a button which looks like
       `<span class="btn btn-default fileinput-button" title="Add files…">
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
        <span>Add files…</span>
        <input id="fileUploadComponent" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="">
        </span>`

I am trying to identify this button with

```
//input[@type='file']"  selector="Xpath"
input[id='fileUploadComponent'][@type='file'] Selector Css
input[id='fileUploadComponent']   Selector Css
```

I don't get any exception, instead in my log it shows the element is clicked but nothing happens in the page (button is not clicked)

Comment: try to verify the xpath (using firebug for example). Please provide the source of the page or atleast the relevant part

Comment: added relevant part of the page

Comment: Might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver