# Firefox Gecko driver cannot click on input element with type "file"

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am automating a page with two file upload buttons across all browsers. Here is the code snippet:

```
WebElement thumbnailClick = driver.findElement(By.id("PageForm_tile_src"));
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)");
thumbnailClick.click();
```

This is the click on the first upload button, and this works perfectly in Chrome, but trying to run on Firefox gecko driver throws an `InvalidArgumentException: Cannot click <input type=file> elements` error

I have to find these elements by id since there are multiple upload buttons on this page. Why would firefox reject this click when it is easy to do manually and works on any other browser?

Adding HTML of element:

```
<input name="PageForm[tile_src]" id="PageForm_tile_src" type="file">
```

Comment: are you sure element is there in the time code execute ? Did you try thread sleep ?

Comment: Yes it is definitely present, and I did attempt a sleep to ensure that. Same error thrown. It would throw an ElementNotFound error if it wasnt loaded yet anyway

Comment: @NickaBrick Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: @Newcontributor Added the element HTML, however the driver statement cannot be the issue considering it works on Chrome perfectly, and the HTML on firefox is exactly the same as Chrome

Comment: Did you try this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726005/how-to-click-on-input-type-file-across-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver It can be more tricky to navigate there using xpath since you have multiple upload buttons but I think it just might do the trick -.-

Comment: The method in which I find the element with driver doesn't impact the error response of "Cannot click <input type=file> elements"

Comment: @NickaBrick Do you wants to upload the file ? Is this the purpose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox (via geckodriver) is behaving correctly here and Chrome is not. The [W3C WebDriver Specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver), in its description of the [Element Click algorithm in Section 14.1](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#element-click), step 3 states: “If the element is an input element in the file upload state<sup>1</sup> return error with error code invalid argument.”

When the Chromium team completes spec-compliance for chromedriver, it will behave as geckodriver, IEDriverServer.exe, the current preview version of Microsoft’s driver implementation for Edge, and Apple’s just released driver implementation for Safari 12 all behave.

To successfully upload files using WebDriver, you should use the `sendKeys` method with the full path to the file you want to upload.

<sup>1</sup>Ed. note: ”In the file upload state” is spec-language for an `<input type="file">` element.

Comment: Thanks for the info! When using the `sendKeys` method, does the file explorer open up to a default location the browser chooses as well? This is the behavior when clicking on it in chrome driver currently

Comment: For the ChromeDriver I was able to use a direct path in the `sendKeys` method, however the same direct path to the file I want to upload does not work in GeckoDriver. Any reason for this?

Comment: File uploading for geckodriver via sendKeys is not globally broken. The [WebDriver Herald](https://webdriver-herald.herokuapp.com) shows tests for file uploading working in both the Selenium project test suite and the Web Platform Tests project test suite.

Comment: That may be the case globally, however in my situation, the Chrome Driver finds my .jpg file and gecko driver does not. Does the gecko driver behave in a different way still, since you we're referencing differences between the upload file behavior previously?